# A man was found on the grassland

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking, situation

A man bought a package. On the next day, his body was found on a grassland. The package was unopened. He was dead.

What happened'?

> Hint: He did not need to consume anything (or anything inside the package), neither was the package’s content the cause of death.

---

**If you think this question is too broad:**

> Question is not a duplicate of the parachute riddle, neither is it too
>   broad. The  answer was found easily by Phylyp. Also the answer (death cause) is related to the description, so it clearly was **not**
>   too broad. (For example: A killer killed him wouldn't make sense, as it has nothing to do with the description of the riddle).

Comment: Looks like it's too broad. He could have died from any cause, natural or not. If the cause of death is related to the package, you should state it in your riddle, and probably add some other details to avoid hundreds of valid answers.

Comment: Edited it, thanks for pointing this out @xhienne

Comment: Is the man found in the grassland or the street? The title and description disagree.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dead in a Field](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16889/dead-in-a-field)

Comment: It's not. The package was airdropped onto him as Phylyp suggested.

Comment: But you don't really buy a package...you buy something and it gets sent in a package

Comment: I don't think you're going to convince anyone to reopen your question by simply asserting that it isn't too broad. Instead of arguing, you could just add a hint or two and solve the problem rather quickly. You say "Also the answer (death cause) is related to the description, so it clearly was not too broad." This might be a good argument if you had previously stated in your question that the cause of death was related to the description. Why don't you just state this explicitly in your question instead of arguing that it was already implied?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm, this sounds like a chestnut.

The package was:

> Bought by the person, and delivered by [air-dropping it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airdrop), and it struck him on his head during the air-drop, killing him.

Comment: Sorry for the broad question, this is not the anwer. Anyway, nice try though! :)

Comment: OK, based on your recent edit, I've updated the answer accordingly, let's see if this is any closer :-)

Comment: You guessed it, even if others thought its "too broad"... Well done! :D

Comment: Interesting, I too thought Kepotx's answer was the right one. Thanks @UnknownBrightness ... although I can't claim 100% credit for this, I recall reading an old story (murder mystery?) about a WW1 pilot who accidentally kills the girl he loves by doing something similar.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe the package was supposed to be open sooner, as it was...

> a parachute. As the men failed to open it in the air, he crash on the ground, dying instantly

Comment: This has *got* to be it. +1.

Comment: That probably was the intended answer, even though the package *was* the cause of death.

Comment: @Acccumulation wasn't the intended answer, it was an airdrop as Phylyp suggested.

Comment: @UnknownBrightness then why did you post a comment on Phlylyp answer saying it wasn't?

Comment: @Kepotx there was a ealier version of his answer, which was wrong. After this, i edited the question and stated my comment. Then he corrected his answer and now it's right.