# What was in the dead person's bag?

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, knowledge, situation, mystery

There are two people—they went to the city, and one of them died. The dead person's bag is closed and the living person's bag is open.

**What was in the dead person's bag?**

Comment: if duplicate, I think I prefer this version, with two people

Comment: @deepthought yes, I do too much like the version with two people, but, in all honestly, this one has many problems with grammar and formatting that really need to be fixed before we can point fingers at who did what and decide whether this counts as a duplicate or not.

Comment: I don't have edit privileges, so my suggested edit is currently waiting in the queue.

Comment: The answer could be just about anything — e.g., lunch or laundry — if you don't impose restrictions.   The obvious (?) one would be that both people were involved in similar events (more similar than just ''they [both] went to the city''), and that these events led to the death of one of them.

Answer (score 1):

> This question is most likely a duplicate of [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16889/dead-in-a-field), so, my answer is
>
>  **PARACHUTE**
>
>  The two of them jumped out of a plane; the person whose parachute deployed survived the fall, but the person whose parachute failed died.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [Alex's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/16889/19765#16893) to [the other question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/16889/19765)
works fairly well here, too. 
I'll give it a minor tweak:

The bags contain

> medicine. 
> Both people are highly allergic,
> and were exposed to an allergen. 
> The guy who survived managed to get to his medicine in time;
> the guy who died did not.

Answer (score 0):

The bags are

> essentially wallets. 
> They contained cash, securities, jewelry, precious metals,
> and/or whatever. 
> Both people were mugged by armed criminals. 
> The guy who lived opened his bag and turned over the loot;
> the other guy refused to comply, and was shot. 
> And/or stabbed or bludgeoned to death.